# Share node.js application to different networks

Tags: node.js, express

I need to know is it possible or is there a way to send my localhost node application to see **from different networks** via a public IP or something like that without hosting application.

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

if my public IP was 112.134.44.30, Is it possible to share my application to others via `112.134.44.30:3000`

Answer (score 2):

From different networks? No, you cannot.

However, you can access your app via another device on your same network, by configuring express to run your application on `0.0.0.0` ( broadcast )

```
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:  ' + 3000);
});
```

and you can access to your application from other devices through `112.134.44.30:3000`